# How to turn off WSTestClient logging client name when running tests?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, ws-client

When I run tests in Play 2.6.x that are using the `WsTestClient` like:

```
WsTestClient.withClient { client => ...
```

I see in the logs:

```
[info] p.a.t.WsTestClient$SingletonWSClient - createNewClient: name = ws-test-client-1
```

Which I believe is coming [from this line](https://github.com/gprathore/Test/blob/master/framework/src/play-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/test/WSTestClient.scala#L162)

Why is it logging as Info if it's set at log-level warn? Can I silence the noise somehow?

Comment: Are you using a custom build of Play? Because the code you linked is not the code used to release Play. Here is the code for the latest version: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.10/framework/src/play-ahc-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/test/WSTestClient.scala#L167. You can silent it by configuring logback to not log `info` messages for that class.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you for linking to the appropriate source,